# Auto update SQL records when select query executed

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way how to update records which are returned by select query automatically in SQL?

Comment: of course there is, it is basic sql scripting. For example: you can put your records (returned by `SELECT` query) in a temporary table and then join this with your main table (the one you want to update). Give us some more informations and we will be able to help you better.

Comment: There is no trigger on SELECT statements if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can not Update after SELECT is executed
But the opposite is possible with [OUTPUT clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/output-clause-sample-code-with-insert-update-delete-sql-server-2005.aspx) as follows

```
/*
create table mySampleTable (
    Id int,
    Selected bit
)

insert into mySampleTable select 1,null
insert into mySampleTable select 2,null
insert into mySampleTable select 3,null
*/

update mySampleTable
    set Selected = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is possible too. In the OUTPUT clause of an UPDATE query, you can access both old values (using DELETED prefix) and new values (using INSERTED prefix).

Comment: how to use where /top clause in this query?

Comment: If you want to limit number of rows displayed by OUTPUT clause, you could only limit rows affected by UPATE command. Just Update limited number of rows using a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: nope. A SELECT query just fetches data from existing tables. The results from the SELECT query might be inserted in a new table using an INTO clause, but the original data will not be touched.

You might create a stored procedure if you want a SELECT and an UPDATE query combined into one operation.